# How to : autorotation on iPad and portrait only on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode3.2, autorotate, universal

Hi I have just started iPhone programming. I created a universal app for iPad and iPhone in Xcode 3.2 and evrerything is working fine. But now I want to implement following feature in that app:

It should support autorotation on iPad and be portrait only on iPhone.

I have no idea how to do that.

I have an AppDelegate_iPad delegate file,
an AppDelegate_iPhone delegate file,
and a viewcontroller under Shared tab and is share by both of these delegates.

Any ideas how can I implement that feature. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vik

Answer (score 3):

In the view controller(s) for the view(s) where you want to implement this rotation behavior, do the check inside the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation {     
    UIDevice* thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if (thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apps running iOS 6+ will also want to implement ViewController's:

```
- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

and/or AppDelegate's:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

E.g.,

```
- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```